# MongoDB filter a single value against a array list

Tags: database, mongodb, filter, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am trying to figure out a way to filter a single value against an array in aggregation. For example i have below data:

```
{ "user" : "InternetBot", "userid" : 001, "timestamp" : "2020-02-22T00:51:07Z", "title" : "Australia" }

{ "user" : "ArchiveBot", "userid" : 031, "timestamp" : "2020-02-22T00:51:07Z", "title" : "Australia" }

{ "user" : "David", "userid" : 312, "timestamp" : "2020-02-22T00:51:07Z", "title" : "Another Book" }

{ "user" : "Tim", "userid" : 111, "timestamp" : "2020-02-22T00:51:07Z", "title" : "A novel" }

{ "user" : "AutoBot", "userid" : 222, "timestamp" : "2020-02-22T00:51:07Z", "title" : "A paint" }
```

I have a list recorded all the bot user, usch as:

[InternetBot, AutoBot, ArchiveBot ]

I wanted to filter user field against this list and only keep document whoes user is in this bot list, i.e output below:

{ "user" : "InternetBot", "userid" : 001, "timestamp" : "2020-02-22T00:51:07Z", "title" : "Australia" }

{ "user" : "ArchiveBot", "userid" : 031, "timestamp" : "2020-02-22T00:51:07Z", "title" : "Australia" }

{ "user" : "AutoBot", "userid" : 222, "timestamp" : "2020-02-22T00:51:07Z", "title" : "A paint" }

I also need to do this in Aggregation since I need to perform other stages as well.

I tried both `$filter` and `$match` but unable to make it work. This seems a stupid question but if anyone can help I will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the complete document and the required output? Also, write what query did you try?

Comment: In aggregation: `{$match:{"user": {$in:["InternetBot", "AutoBot", "ArchiveBot"]}}}`. 
In query: the same criteria, only without $match